# Not getting expected rows after inner joins after joining two data tables

Tags: c#, linq

I'm joining two data tables on composite key i.e account no. and amount but according pictures I've attached I'm getting only one row after join but I should get 2 rows.

```
var query = from dataRows1 in clearingDTAlias.AsEnumerable()
            join dataRows2 in excelDT.AsEnumerable()
            on new
            {
                Account_No = dataRows1.Field<string>("Account_No"),
                Amount = dataRows1.Field<string>("Withdraw_Amount_Requested")
            } equals new
            {
                Account_No = dataRows2.Field<string>("Account_No"),
                Amount = dataRows2.Field<string>("Amount")
            }
            select joinDT.LoadDataRow(new object[]
            {
                dataRows2.Field<string>("Account_No"),
                dataRows2.Field<string>("Amount"),
                dataRows2.Field<string>("Code"),
                dataRows2.Field<string>("Row_No"),
            }, true);

if (query.Any())
{
    var query2 = query.GroupBy(test => test.Field<string>("Row_No")).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList();
    if (query2.Any())
        joinDT = query2.CopyToDataTable();
    else
        joinDT = excelDT.Clone();
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to attach any pictures?

Answer (score 0):

Use below group by clause to get the grouped rows from query.

```
var query2 = query.GroupBy(test => test.Field<string>("Row_No"))
                  .Select(grp => grp.Key).ToList()
```

Comment: Grouping is working fine, the problem is in getting common rows

Comment: Please post the expected output once